# jQuery AJAX single file upload

Tags: jquery

I know this question has been asked a lot, and I tried at least 10 different codes to run this without success.

I'm trying to upload a single file with [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but it doesn't work. The code below always outputs:

> please choose a file' because the file's name is not set or something

---

#### HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var files;

    $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
    function prepareUpload(event){
      files = event.target.files;
    };
    $(':button').click(function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        $.each(files, function(key, value){
          formData.append(key, value);
        });
        alert(formData);
        $.ajax({
          url: 'check.php',  
          type: 'GET',
          data: formData,
          success: function(data){ $('#result').html(data); }, 
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
        });
    });
  });
});
```

#### PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['file'])){
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    if(isset($filename) && !empty($filename)){
        echo 'sup my man?!';
    }else{
        echo 'please choose a file';
    }
}else{
    echo 'not set';
}
```

I don't know what the problem is, I know it's in the `FormData` object creation because the alert - good to go, doesn't work.

BTW it is really important for me that it would be written in jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried
[**this plugin**](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)

    . I have used it 2 or may be 3 times, but it works like charm.

Comment: I use the plUpload plugin.  Seems to be one of the more popular ones and its worked well for me.  http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: thanks guys, CodeMonk yes I tried to use this code, this is pretty much the code in the question. and Johnny thank you, but I'm tried to solve this problem I don't want to use plugins.

Answer (score 31):

After hours of searching and looking for answer, finally I made it!!!!!
Code is below :))))

**HTML:**

```
<form id="fileinfo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
    <label>File to stash:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required />
</form>
<input type="button" value="Stash the file!"></input>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#uploadBTN').on('click', function(){ 
        var fd = new FormData($("#fileinfo"));
        //fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',  
            type: 'POST',
            data: fd,
            success:function(data){
                $('#output').html(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

In the `upload.php` file you can access the data passed with `$_FILES['file']`.

Thanks everyone for trying to help:)

I took the answer from here (with some changes)
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files_via_AJAX_without_FormData_objects)

Comment: Improvement: don't pass the complete formdata to the constructor. Use var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
data:  formData

Comment: You need to use tjm1706's improvements to use this solution. I've tried it with and without this improvement.

Answer (score 14):

**A. Grab file data from the file field**

The first thing to do is bind a function to the change event on your file field and a function for grabbing the file data:

```
// Variable to store your files
var files;

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);

// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event)
{
  files = event.target.files;
}
```

This saves the file data to a file variable for later use.

**B. Handle the file upload on submit**

When the form is submitted you need to handle the file upload in its own AJAX request. Add the following binding and function:

```
$('form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

// Catch the form submit and upload the files
function uploadFiles(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

// START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

// Create a formdata object and add the files
var data = new FormData();
$.each(files, function(key, value)
{
    data.append(key, value);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php?files',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            submitForm(event, data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
}
```

What this function does is create a new formData object and appends each file to it. It then passes that data as a request to the server. 2 attributes need to be set to false:

- processData - Because jQuery will convert the files arrays into
  strings and the server can't pick it up.
- contentType - Set this to false because jQuery defaults to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and doesn't send the files. Also setting it to multipart/form-data
  doesn't seem to work either.

**C. Upload the files**

Quick and dirty php script to upload the files and pass back some info:

```
<?php // You need to add server side validation and better error handling here

$data = array();

if(isset($_GET['files']))
{  
$error = false;
$files = array();

$uploaddir = './uploads/';
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir .basename($file['name'])))
    {
        $files[] = $uploaddir .$file['name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $error = true;
    }
}
$data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your files') : array('files' => $files);
}
else
{
    $data = array('success' => 'Form was submitted', 'formData' => $_POST);
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

IMP: Don't use this, write your own.

**D. Handle the form submit**

The success method of the upload function passes the data sent back from the server to the submit function. You can then pass that to the server as part of your post:

```
function submitForm(event, data)
{
  // Create a jQuery object from the form
$form = $(event.target);

// Serialize the form data
var formData = $form.serialize();

// You should sterilise the file names
$.each(data.files, function(key, value)
{
    formData = formData + '&filenames[]=' + value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        // Handle errors here
        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
    }
});
}
```

**Final note**

This script is an example only, you'll need to handle both server and client side validation and some way to notify users that the file upload is happening. I made a project for it on [Github](https://github.com/Abban/jQueryFileUpload) if you want to see it working.

[**Referenced From**](https://github.com/Abban/jQueryFileUpload)

Comment: Thanks again, but I already tried to use it without success.

Comment: can you show a demo / screendump / anything to see what's happening!

Comment: http://sell4you.co.il/study/ajaxFileUpload.html

Comment: where are you uploading the file? as I can see the source-code doesn't say much. where's the `action` of your form?

Comment: the action is the url inside the '$.ajax' function, if you specifying this you shouldn't specify an action at the form tab