# How to send multiple image from MVC view to controller using Ajax in array format?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, image, model-view-controller

I am trying to send multiple images using Ajax but with out form data as my bunch of data is in array format.

my jquery function is,

```
 $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
            //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
            var customers = new Array();

                var row = $(this);
                var files1 = $("#file").get(0).files;
            var customer = {};
            alert(files1);
                customer.EmpPic = "";
                customer.FirstName = txtFirstName.value;
                customer.SecondName = txtSecondName.value;
                customer.ThirdName = txtThirdName.value;
                customer.Tribe = ddltribe.value;
                customer.NationalID = txtNationalId.value;
                customer.Address = txtAddress.value;
                customer.Location = ddlcityy.value;
                customer.Education = txtEducation.value;
                customer.PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNo.value;
                customer.FamilyTree = "";
                customer.SignaturePath ="";
                customer.StempPath = "";
                customer.StempChangePath = "";
                customer.FamilyCertificatePath = "";
                customer.IBAN = txtIban.value;
                customer.IBANPath = "";      
                customers.push(customer);


            //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddEmployee",
                data: JSON.stringify(customers),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                }
            });
        });
```

Above here I am sending same fields that I have in my sql table "Employee". I need to send two images from this array that are,

```
   <input type="file" title="search image" id="EmpImage" name="file"/>
   <input type="file" title="search image" id="Document" name="file"/>
```

my controller is,

```
 public JsonResult AddEmployee(List<Employee> Emp)
        {                
                return Json();            
        }
```

Here I am getting all employee data need to send these images too

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks

Now i am getting Images by using this code,

```
var formData = new FormData();
            var profile = $("#EmpImage").get(0).files;
            var Iban = $("#Document").get(0).files;



            //setting ArrayData to Json Object
            formData.append("mydata", JSON.stringify(customers));
            formData.append("EmpImage", profile[0]);
            formData.append("Document", Iban[0]);

HttpPostedFileBase EmpImage= Request.Files["EmpImage"];
            HttpPostedFileBase Document= Request.Files["Document"];
            var data = Request.Form;
            return null;
```

but still not able to get data passing in the form of object "customers"

Comment: What is your scenario? Are the images uploaded by the user, displayed on the page, and then you want to save them to the database, or...?

Comment: @mortb my mistake in post i mention <img> tag not i added i have input type file i need to pass it to controller with my data. i dont want to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your are using `form` element and your controls are inside the tag, you can simply serialize the whole `form` and append it to your `FormData`. This will also include any files generated with `<input type="file" name="myImage" .../>`:

```
var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("AddEmployee", "Home")',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,         
});
```

`Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddEmployee(List<Employee> Emp)
{                
  return Json();            
}
```

If your model does not include a property for `HttpPostedFileBase`, then you can do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(List<Employee> Emp, HttpPostedFileBase EmpImage)
{
return Json();
}
```

Regarding your scenario since you are using plain `HTML` and without `form` I am assuming, your generated `FormData` looks correct so you would need to access your form data in your `Controller` with the associated tag that you have given to your model array like this:

```
var emp = Request.Form["mydata"];
```

Comment: i am using simple html

Comment: @Doc Try this: `Request.Form.GetValues("mydata");` or `Request.Form["mydata"]` on the `Controller` side.

Comment: I just did this var emp = Request.Form["mydata"]; it worked !

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts:

- Build your ajax request on client-side
- Bind the request data to your model (using c# model binding) on server-side

For the client side, you can find inspiration in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214608/jquery-ajax-single-file-upload).
Basically, do not forget to add the `enctype="multipart/form-data` to the `<form>` tag, and arrange the request data using the `FormData` JS class.

For the server side, use the `IFormFile` c# class in your model.

```cs
public class Employee {
    ...
    public IFormFile EmpPic { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Document{ get; set; }
}
```