# How to upload a file in HTML and save the data in a variable in separate JS file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, file-upload

So I have a webpage and am using the `<input type="file">` tag. The user should be able to select a file (not multiple), then I have to check if it is a .csv and set the data to a JavaScript variable (string) to further process it. The JavaScript-Code has to be in a separate file, so I can't put the code in `<script>` tags in my HTML file but rather inside a function called after a button press or something.

I tried php and ajax, with no success. I have no experience with php, so I don't really know what went wrong, but my php code just get's printed on the page:

[page after php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Tqx.png)

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

As for the ajax, I used several posts on Stack Overflow with such as:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/13267452)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21222404/13267452)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939229/13267452)

I would prefer no plug-ins if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a web server running? Does it have PHP installed/enabled?

Comment: No, I don't. Will try that. Does that also explain why ajax isn't working?